# Transform a string into array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string like this:

```
string = "locations[0][street]=street&locations[0][street_no]=
         34&locations[1][street]=AnotherStreet&locations[1][street_no]=43";
```

What must I do with this string so i can play with `locations[][]` as I wish?

Comment: Where do you get the string from? It may be easier to create a proper JS object from the beginning.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use `split` using `&` as delimeter then use `eval` to evaluate each part. Can't you have more "proper" data source though?

Comment: This is how i get my data and i can't do anything to change that unfortunately.

Need to parse this as it is and right now i just can't thing at a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a parser:

```
var myStr = "locations[0][street]=street&locations[0][street_no]=34&locations[1][street]=AnotherStreet&locations[1][street_no]=43";


function parseArray(str) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var tmp = myStr.split('&');
    var lastIdx;
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        var parts = tmp[i].split('=');
        var m = parts[0].match(/\[[\w]+\]/g);
        var idx = m[0].substring(1, m[0].length - 1);
        var key = m[1].substring(1, m[1].length - 1);
        if (lastIdx != idx) {
            lastIdx = idx;
            arr.push({});
        }
        arr[idx * 1][key] = parts[1];
    }
    return arr;
}

var myArr = parseArray(myStr);
```

Comment: +1 nice solution, although I think you meant `push` and not `add`

Comment: @Joey - push is the instance method, which also would work.  Array.add(instance, value) is adds a new index to an array.

Comment: it throws this: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'add', tried push, same error

Comment: I'm just not sure you're getting much browser coverage with that, but either way.

Comment: @Joey - touche!  Gomoi got precisely what you were talking about... will update w/ push, not .add..

Comment: @Gomoi Mihai Bogdan - try again (I replaced Array.add with arrayInstance.push(..)) - +1 to Joey for noting the cross browser on Array.add(..,..)

Answer (score 0):

As Shadow wizard said, using split and eval seems to be the solution.
You need to initialize locations first, if you want to avoid an error.

```
stringArray=string.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++){
    eval(stringArray[i]);
}
```

However, you might need to pay attention to what street and street_no are.
As is, it will produce an error because street is not defined.

Edit: and you'll need to fully initialize locations with as many item as you'll have to avoid an error.

Comment: Be very careful using eval like this with a string coming from an external source.  Unless the source is 100% trusted this is very dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, i know this is some dangerous stuff, I try to avoid using it unless it's the only way (or if it's easier than the rest by far).
Using regexp like Brian did seems a safer (and cleaner) way but a longer one.